# HowTo: First click animation 1, second click animation 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, navigation, hamburger-menu

I am about to build a mobile burger menu that animates as follows:

*1) Click 1 on burger menu: menu open animation...nav links fade-in last

2) Click 2 on burger menu: nav links fade-out first...menu close animation*

I am animating with jQuery:

```
/* mobile menu fx */
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#nav-icon4').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('#mobile-menu').toggleClass('open');
        $('#mobile-menu-elements').toggleClass('open');
        $('#mobile-menu-blurredBg').toggleClass('open');
        $('#mobile-menu-elements-ul').toggleClass('open');
    });

});
```

**How can I set a different class for the second click (closing the menu)?**

Comment: Just define your closed menu in your differents classes in your css. When you will toggle the class open, it will loose it and reload the main css values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in the JS side, why dont you try to add a count variable, see if it works:

```
/* mobile menu fx */
$(document).ready(function(){

    var count = 0;

    $('#nav-icon4').click(function(){
       if(count == 0){
           // do something in the first click;
           count++;
       } else{
           // do something in the second click;
            count=0;;
       }
    // Dont know which one goes in the first or in the second click
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('#mobile-menu').toggleClass('open');
    $('#mobile-menu-elements').toggleClass('open');
    $('#mobile-menu-blurredBg').toggleClass('open');
    $('#mobile-menu-elements-ul').toggleClass('open');
    });

});
```

I know it's a bit dirty and there could be better ways. I haven't checked if it works, but this is just one of them, hope it helps.